# Are layman level questions about the availability or price of a concrete food on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, migration

I am a moderator on Cooking. Every now and then, we get questions which we close because they are not about cooking, but about buying food. They generally fall into two categories:

1. **Why does food X cost as much as it costs?** 
   Examples: [Why are berries so expensive?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/why-are-berries-so-expensive), [Why do chocolate bars cost less than the sum of their ingredients](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103735/why-do-chocolate-bars-expensive-ones-like-lindt-cost-less-than-the-sum-of-thi)
2. **Why is food Y not being sold?** Example: [Why is it impossible to find potato flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104035/why-does-whole-partial-potato-flour-is-rare-to-impossible-to-find-while-potato). I remember also another question asking why a specific kind of biscuit is only available plain and never chocolate-covered, but couldn't find the question itself.

When we explain to askers that these questions are out of scope because one would need economic knowledge to create and verify(!) an answer, not cooking knowledge, they sometimes suggest that the questions get migrated here, to Economics.SE.

What is your take on this type of questions? For each of the two categories - should we always migrate them, never migrate them, or ask here for each specific case?

There is no flood of such questions, we probably get 4-5 of them per year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the site want questions on "everyday economics" about consumer markets?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/does-the-site-want-questions-on-everyday-economics-about-consumer-markets)

Comment: Oops - turns out I asked this a few years ago already. Please close as a dupe. https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/does-the-site-want-questions-on-everyday-economics-about-consumer-markets?rq=1

Comment: See you again in four years!

Comment: @Giskard hehe, I hope I'm capable of learning. But the next four years will show it best :)